# Android startSupportActionMode breaks in appcompat 22.0.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

In the newest appcompat v 22.0.0 `startSupportActionMode()` breaks. The only thing needed for breaking it is simply updating which library is used. The functionality still works but the view is just all white.

Using startSupportActionMode with following gradle build: `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"`

Gives following results:
[image: actionmode working as it should]

But with gradle build: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'`

I get following: 
[image: actionmode failing]

Comment: check this tutorial  http://tech-papers.org/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was enough to overwrite a appcompat style in the app theme:

```
<!-- Theme -->
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/my_custom_color</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps. Please note, that there is **no *android:* prefix** in the item name. This is important!

Comment: Had the same problem and this worked for me, thanks.  This issue is being tracked as android bug 160033 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160033 I used my accent color as suggested in the comments there and it looks better than the old dark action mode color: <item name="actionModeBackground">?attr/colorAccent</item>